# angular-ui how to design parent list view with search parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What is the design pattern for next problem?
I have a state 'a.list'. It shows list data and filter. When i change the filter it reloads the 'a.list' state with new search parameters (?type=emp&ageFrom=3...)
[image]

I want to have a child state to show details of selected item 'a.list.detail'.
I'm wondering how to do this in best way because i want to keep my filter parameters when i back to list view from detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a state for details with parameters and you can access it in this way

```
      state('yiur new state', {
      url: '/new',
      params: {
        type: null,
ageFrom:null
      },
      templateUrl: 'new.html',
      controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
         $scope.type= $stateParams.type;
$scope.ageFrom= $stateParams.ageFrom;
      }
    });
```

When you get back to back to list view you can be able to get back the details